# PHP continues execution of code in try block after exception is thrown and caught

Tags: php, api, exception, jwt, try-catch

I'm currently writing an API in PHP which uses a JWT for authentication, and I'm running into a strange issue in my `try-catch` blocks. If I pass in no JWT or a malformed JWT with my HTTP request, my serverside code will throw an exception as expected and then execute code in the relevant `catch` block, sending back a `401: Access Denied` response. However, the sever appears to  then continue execution of the remaining code in the `try` block, executing a SQL query and sending the results as if nothing had happened.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
try {
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $access_key, array('HS256')); // Exception thrown here

    ...

    setResponseCode(200);
    echo json_encode($results);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    setResponseCode(401, "Access denied: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the order of events: First an exception is thrown at the first line in the `try` block. Then the code in the `catch` block executes. Then the remaining code in the `try` block executes.

This is obviously a huge security flaw, but I can't figure out why it might be happening. What exactly is going on?

**EDIT: Additional context**

This is the only code in the PHP file that sits above the `try-catch` block, and no code exists below it. I don't see how it would be likely to interfere with the try-catch block.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once 'config/core.php';
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    if (strcmp($name, "Authorization") == 0) {
        $jwt = $value;
    }
}
```

And this is how the API is being called from Javascript:

```
axios
  .get(API_URL + "foo.php")
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.body);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.statusText);
  });
```

Since no JWT is supplied, an error should be printing to the console. Instead, I get an automatic warning from the browser that my request received a 401 response, but then the object I requested prints out to the console as if I supplied correct authentication information.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome console output]

Comment: Continuing execution in the block after a `throw` is simply something that PHP _will not do_. The likelihood that this is a PHP bug is very low, and it's far more likely that there is a bug in the surrounding code. Additionally, remember that a catch block does not halt execution unless you put something in it that does.

Comment: Do you need an `exit();` afer you set the response code? With ajax and with setting a `Location: ` header, not including the `exit();` afterwards means things are overwritten and there are unexpected results (like other functions returning values that they shouldn't be).

Comment: When you catch an exception, you stop the automatic termination, you are basically saying I can handle this situation. So you have to handle it. If you want the code (after the `catch` )not to run, you need an exit in the `catch`

Comment: @Sammitch @RiggsFolly There is no additional code after the `catch`, so nothing else should be happening afterwards. I've added some additional context to the original post that might be helpful.

Comment: @AaronJ I'm not using a location header, I'm using axios instead of ajax, and there's no code remaining after the catch block. Would it still be necessary to include an `exit();` statement?

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure, but you are setting a header. What happens when you try it?

Comment: @AaronJ no change, still getting the buggy behavior

Comment: Fro the screenshot we can't tell where the data that's being output is coming from. Maybe the variable that has data has already been set before the 401 message.